# How to Sort Hashmap in javascript based on Value

Tags: javascript, sorting, hashmap

Here I am getting hashmap finalMap from another function. I want to sort this map on basis of value and I am doing the following but without any result.Can you suggest how to sort this map .

```
  function onSubmit(values)
  {       
    finalMap[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
        yield* [...this.entries()].sort((a, b) => a[1] < b[1]);
     }
     for(let [key,value] of finalMap)
     {
         console.log(key+ " " + value)
     }
     values.preventDefault();
   }
```

Comment: `a[1] < b[1]` returns true or false ... sort callback should return a negative number, 0 or a positive number - is the problem that your result is not sorted, or just nothing?

Comment: what is a `hashmap` anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much more simpler approach would be

```
const finalMap = new Map([...map.entries()].sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]));
```